# I want to check before appending if the element is already there or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.negative').on('click',function() {
  var saveImg = $(this).parents('.img_listing_long').find('img').clone();
  $(list).append(saveImg);
});
```

If the element is already present in the list then it shouldn't be cloned.

Comment: Do you have something in each image element which uniquely identifies it? e.g. an ID or a data attribute or something? We need a bit more context about your HTML, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Update it:

```
$('.negative').on('click',function() {
  if( $(list).find('img').length == 0 )
  {
     var saveImg = $(this).parents('.img_listing_long').find('img').clone();
     $(list).append(saveImg);
  }
});
```

Or put the class on img tag like class name "myimage" then:

```
$('.negative').on('click',function() {
      if( $(list).find('.myimage').length == 0 )
      {
         var saveImg = $(this).parents('.img_listing_long').find('img').clone();
         $(list).append(saveImg);
      }
    });
```